# cellForRowAtIndexPath is called twice

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I'm displaying a dynamic table view initialised through a storyboard.
Nothing fancy, just initialising 3 cell with text labels.

Here is what actually happens:

```
2014-08-15 12:39:19.909 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] numberOfSectionsInTableView
2014-08-15 12:39:19.926 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] numberOfSectionsInTableView
2014-08-15 12:39:19.927 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] numberOfRowsInSection
2014-08-15 12:39:19.929 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 0
2014-08-15 12:39:19.943 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] Displaying row: 0
2014-08-15 12:39:19.943 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 1
2014-08-15 12:39:19.945 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] Displaying row: 1
2014-08-15 12:39:19.945 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 2
2014-08-15 12:39:19.946 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] Displaying row: 2
2014-08-15 12:39:19.947 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] numberOfSectionsInTableView
2014-08-15 12:39:19.947 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] numberOfRowsInSection
2014-08-15 12:39:19.948 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 0
2014-08-15 12:39:19.949 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] Displaying row: 0
2014-08-15 12:39:19.949 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 1
2014-08-15 12:39:19.950 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] Displaying row: 1
2014-08-15 12:39:19.951 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 2
2014-08-15 12:39:19.952 PopTestAnimation[31825:60b] Displaying row: 2
```

It seems like every cell is initialised twice for some reason. Any ideas why?

Here is the [code](https://github.com/nderkach/popanimationtest/blob/master/PopTestAnimation/TraffleViewController.m)

Comment: From what I've observed in my apps that is typical behavior.

Comment: If this is a `UITableViewController` then it calls `reloadData` in `viewWillAppear` the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked the storyboard file. Inside the storyboard for **TraffleViewController** (subclass of UITableViewController) you have a **UITableViewWrapper** and another **UITableView** inside it.

There should only be a single **UITableViewWrapper** and no other **UITableView** inside it. As there is a UITableView inside a UITableViewWrapper there are two calls to:

```
cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

If you do a debug and print the instances of UITableView inside:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you will find two separate instances of UITableView.
Please follow  below steps to solve it.

> 1.Remove the view called "Table View" from storyboard.
>
> 2.Drag a UITableView inside TraffleViewController
>
> 3.Set the datasource and delegate of UITableView to TraffleViewController.

Comment: Indeed that was the case, I have no idea why that happened. Thanks!